# using .format() with a lot of replacement fields

Tags: python

I have a long string with many replacement fields that I then format with:

```
firstRep  = replacementDict['firstRep']
secondRep = replacementDict['secondRep']
.
.
.
nthRep    = replacementDict['nthRep']

newString = oldString.format(firstRep = firstRep, 
                             secondRep = secondRep,...,
                             nthRep = nthRep)
```

Is there a way to avoid having to set every option individually and use a looped approach to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply unpack the dictionary like this

```
replacementDict = {}
replacementDict["firstRep"]  = "1st, "
replacementDict["secondRep"] = "2nd, "
replacementDict["thirdRep"]  = "3rd, "

print "{firstRep}{secondRep}{thirdRep}".format(**replacementDict)
# 1st, 2nd, 3rd,
```

Quoting from the [Format Examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples),

```
Accessing arguments by name:

>>>
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W')
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
>>> coord = {'latitude': '37.24N', 'longitude': '-115.81W'}
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(**coord)
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [unpack argument dicts with a `**` prefix](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
newString = oldString.format(**replacementDict)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.format_map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) which is provided *exactly* for this usecase:

```
old_string.format_map(replacement_dict)
```

Note: `format_map` is provided only in python3.2+. In python2 you can use `**` unpacking (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) related question), *howerver* this forces python to copy the dictionary and is thus a bit slower and uses more memory.

Comment: Wow, that exists? (Since Python 3, yes! Cool.)